# Every time credential=storage.get() returns None

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

```
storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
credential = storage.get()
if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
    FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                   request.user)
    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
else:
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credential.authorize(http)
    service = build("storage", "v1", http=http)
    req = service.objects().copy(
        sourceBucket="template1",
        sourceObject="index.html",
        destinationBucket="jatin1",
        destinationObject="index1.html",
        body = {}
        )
    resp = req.execute()
```

**I am using django gae app. I am trying to use google cloud storage api. But storage.get() returnd None every time. I checked database. There is CredentialsModel table is generated and also credential field has a data. Though why credential = storage.get() returns None and go in if condition except else.**

Here the function which generate the credentail and save it in CredentialsModel table.

```
def auth_return(request):
  if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, request.REQUEST['state'],
                                 request.user):
    return  HttpResponseBadRequest()
  credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
  storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
  log.info("during auth return>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+str(credential))
  storage.put(credential)
  print "this is the storage", storage
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
```